# A little bit stuck with MVC pattern on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

So I am really trying to understand MVC. I have migrated my app into an MVC(ish) architecture but i still know I have made some mistakes. The most confusing part for me is the communication between view and the controller part. I have defined all my Outlets,Actions(Text Fields, Image Views, button actions) in my controller(UIViewController) class and all the initial stuff like property widths, heights are in my view. Today I saw a post with MVC and M-VC(Massive View Controller). Now I am more confused.

What I want is one single example for my code. Where should I move the outlets and other stuff, and how do I establish a communication between my view and the controller.

Here is my view for a screen:

```swift
class incidentMgmView: UIView, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var textHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker?
    let namePickr = UIPickerView()
    var pickerData = namePicker()

    // Auto Resizing Text Field Functions
    func autoResizeTextView(textView: UITextView){
        textView.clipsToBounds = true
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        textHeightConstraint = textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        textHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        adjustTextViewHeight(txtView: textView)
    }

    func adjustTextViewHeight(txtView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = txtView.frame.size.width
        let newSize = txtView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
    }

    // Exit editing if a touch is registered.
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        endEditing(true)
    }

    // Date Picker View
    func datePick(dateTextField: UITextField){
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker?.addTarget(incidentMgm(), action: #selector(incidentMgm.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
        let pickerToolBar = toolBarPicker().ToolbarPicker(mySelect: #selector(incidentMgm.dismissDatePicker))
        dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar
    }

    // Exit editing if a touch is registered.
    @objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        endEditing(true)
    }

    // Picker View
    func namePick(pickerTextField: UITextField){
        pickerTextField.inputView = namePickr
        namePickr.dataSource = self
        let toolBar = toolBarPicker().ToolbarPicker(mySelect: #selector(incidentMgm.dismissPersonPicker))
        pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.contentSize
    }
```

And here is the controller of this view:

```swift
class incidentMgm: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var neredeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var aTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hangiTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var neTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    //
    var views = incidentMgmView() // View Class
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imagepos = 0
    var camimg = UIImage.init(named: "camicon")
    var imgArray = [UIImageView]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initialize()
        views.namePick(pickerTextField: nameTextField)
        views.datePick(dateTextField: dateTxtField)
        views.autoResizeTextView(textView: myTextView)
        imgTap()
    }
    //  Assinging tags and delegates
    func initialize(){
        neTextField.delegate = self
        dateTxtField.delegate = self
        neredeTextField.delegate = self
        hangiTextField.delegate = self
        aTextField.delegate = self
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        myTextView.delegate = self
        views.namePickr.delegate = self
        //  Image stuff
        imgArray.append(imageView)
        imgArray.append(imageView2)
        imgArray.append(imageView3)
        for i in 0...2{
            imgArray[i].image = camimg
            imgArray[i].tag = i
        }
    }
    //  Image Picker Controller Functions
    func imgTap(){
        var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        for imgView in imgArray{
            imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        }
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        _ = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        imagepos = tapGestureRecognizer.view!.tag
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker:UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
            for imgView in imgArray {
                if(imagepos == imgView.tag){
                    imgView.image = image
                    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Skip to the next text field with return button
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        switch textField{
        case neTextField:
            dateTxtField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case dateTxtField:
            neredeTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case neredeTextField:
            nameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case hangiTextField:
            myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case myTextView:
            aTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        default:
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            break
        }
        return true
    }

    @objc func dismissPersonPicker(textField: UITextField){
        hangiTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func dismissDatePicker(textField: UITextField) {
        neredeTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        dateTxtField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }

    internal func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        nameTextField.text = views.pickerData.pickerContent[row]
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return views.pickerData.pickerContent[row]
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        views.adjustTextViewHeight(txtView: myTextView)
    }
}
```

What this view does is it submits a form with text and images in it to my service.

I would be really happy if i had one example to define the MVC pattern for me.
I tried reading lots of forum posts and Apple's MVC documentation, but that didn't help me at all.
Thanks...

Comment: Using MVC won't be helpful you to separate your view and business logic. If you'd like to separate them you need to do some search about MVVM or Viper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommended you to use MVVM for you application design pattern. There is a great amount of information about it online. [Sample Below](https://www.raywenderlich.com/34-design-patterns-by-tutorials-mvvm). On the other hand, I can not recommend you to use Viper, because about this design pattern there is not so much detailed info online. In addition to this, Viper is a good architecture for enourmous projects.

Comment: There is a good basic practice for beginning. You can download from source code from here: https://bitbucket.org/dino4674/mvvmswiftexample-starter/get/25663cc4ee77.zip

Comment: Or examine guide line from here : https://www.toptal.com/ios/swift-tutorial-introduction-to-mvvm

Comment: @Fuzzyy please accept the answer if it was helpful and you consider your question and answer exchange complete.